# jquery .last() firing multiple times when clicking last element only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some tabs with radio buttons in them and want to check when the last option is clicked (by that I mean any radio button in the last tab, not the last radio button).

This is my html:

```html
<div id="smartwizard" class="sw-main sw-theme-default">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs step-anchor">
    <li class="optietabs nav-item done">
      <a href="#step-0" class="nav-link">Lijmlaag
<button class="infotooltip" data-tooltip="lijmlaag is gewoon een dikke laag lijm">
<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button></a>
      <div id="step-0" class="" style="display: none;">
        <form class="" id="step__form" method="post">
          <div class="tab-content2">
            <input type="radio" id="Wit-Lijmlaag" name="Lijmlaag" value="Wit(prijsberekening)($m2*4);">
            <label for="Wit-Lijmlaag">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Wit">
                <p><strong>Wit</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="Grijs-Lijmlaag" name="Lijmlaag" value="Grijs(prijsberekening)($stuksprijs+15);">
            <label for="Grijs-Lijmlaag">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Grijs">
                <p><strong>Grijs</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="optietabs nav-item done">
      <a href="#step-1" class="nav-link">Laminaat
<button class="infotooltip" data-tooltip="Test test test test&nbsp;">
<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button></a>
      <div id="step-1" class="" style="display: none;">
        <form class="" id="step__form" method="post">
          <div class="tab-content2">
            <input type="radio" id="Anti-slip laminaat-Laminaat" name="Laminaat" value="Anti-slip laminaat(prijsberekening)($o*5);">
            <label for="Anti-slip laminaat-Laminaat">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Anti-slip laminaat">
                <p><strong>Anti-slip laminaat</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="Glans laminaat-Laminaat" name="Laminaat" value="Glans laminaat(prijsberekening)($m2*4);">
            <label for="Glans laminaat-Laminaat">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Glans laminaat">
                <p><strong>Glans laminaat</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="Mat laminaat-Laminaat" name="Laminaat" value="Mat laminaat(prijsberekening)($m2*4);">
            <label for="Mat laminaat-Laminaat">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Mat laminaat">
                <p><strong>Mat laminaat</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="Geen-Laminaat" name="Laminaat" value="Geen">
            <label for="Geen-Laminaat">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Geen">
                <p><strong>Geen</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="optietabs nav-item active">
      <a href="#step-2" class="nav-link">Afwerking</a>
      <div id="step-2" class="">
        <form class="" id="step__form" method="post">
          <div class="tab-content2">
            <input type="radio" id="Contoursnijden-Afwerking" name="Afwerking" value="Contoursnijden(prijsberekening)($m2*30);">
            <label for="Contoursnijden-Afwerking">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <div class="ribbon ribbon-top-right">
                  <span>Meest gekozen</span>
                </div>
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Contoursnijden">
                <p><strong>Contoursnijden</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="Schoonsnijden-Afwerking" name="Afwerking" value="Schoonsnijden">
            <label for="Schoonsnijden-Afwerking">
              <div class="afwerking-tab">
                <img class="materiaal-image" src="assets/images/custom/noimgstep.jpg" alt="Schoonsnijden">
                <p><strong>Schoonsnijden</strong></p>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jquery function:

```
$("#smartwizard input:radio").on("click", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection, stepPosition) {
  var form_data = $("#formsid form").serialize();

  $('#formaataantaltab').removeClass('formaataantal-done');
  $('#formaataantaltab').addClass('formaataantal');

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
    data:({form_data: form_data}),
    success:function(data){

      var content = $( $.parseHTML(data) );
      $( "#ajaxresult" ).empty().append( content );
      $('#prijsonder').empty().append($('#prijs').html());
       // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
       $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
    }
  });

  $laatsteopties = $(".optietabs").last();
  $($laatsteopties).on("change", function() {
    console.log('last option clicked');
  });

  $(".optietabs").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 0);
    })
  });
});
```

Where this part is logging when a last option is clicked in the console:

```
  $laatsteopties = $(".optietabs").last();
  $($laatsteopties).on("change", function() {
    console.log('last option clicked');
  });
```

The problem is when I click one radio button, I see the console logging `last option clicked` multiple times, in this case 3, instead of just one time each radio button click.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes it will be, as you are adding an event listener to `$laatsteopties` everytime you click on `#smartwizard input:radio`. Just put the `$laatsteopties = $(".optietabs").last();
  $($laatsteopties).on("change", function() {
    console.log('last option clicked');
  });` out of click handler and it will work perfectly.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure (and so is the HTML formatter) that your HTML is not very valid. Don't wrap a button in a link and dont have a div in a label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added code `$($laatsteopties).on("change", function() {...` *(1)* in block `$("#smartwizard input:radio").on("click", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection, stepPosition) {` *(2)*, so code *(1)* executes three times for each radio button. You need to move code

```
$laatsteopties = $(".optietabs").last();
  $($laatsteopties).on("change", function() {
    console.log('last option clicked');
  });
```

out of code block *(2)*.

Comment: Thank you that did it, I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes.